# jquery chosen, empty String as option

Tags: jquery, grails, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I´m using chosen.js for Dropdowns in a form on a grails-environment.
I want the users to be able to select an empty option, but somehow it is ignored.
There must be a possibility to do this? 
Because the workaround to set an option like "select-none" and later in data-bindig make a if condition if select-none value= "" would be unpretty.

to show my problem :

for example this select :

```
<g:select id="foo" data-placeholder="bar"  class="foo chzn-select" style="width: 245px;" tabindex="4" 
                    from="${['M', ' ', 'F']}" value="foo" name="titel"/>
```

would return :

[image]

Sure this is a nice feature of chosen, but i guess my case is a common case and maybe someone of you already has a solution to override this behaviour

thanks in advance

Comment: Would it help if you include the blank option as the first option in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<g:select name="foo" from="${foos}" noSelection="[' ':' ']"  />
```

Answer (score 21):

You can also set *allow_single_deselect* to true. This will have a 'x' that allows user to deselect the option.

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen({ allow_single_deselect:true });
```

Comment: Note that this is not enough, there has to be an option with an empty value too.

Answer (score 17):

after some research i found this thread

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/93

and my solution was prepending an option via JS before initialisation of chosen

```
$("#id").prepend("<option value='' >&nbsp;</option>");
```

So this one is Resolved, thanks to `&nbsp;` and everyone who had a look at this

Comment: This will hide the deselect option.

Comment: Do not attempt to use this solution and `allow_single_deselect` option at the same time. They do not behave nicely together. That being said this is still a nice solution when separated.

Answer (score 1):

If your select already has a blank option, you can skip the first step.

1 - You can try to use like:

```
$(".chzn-select").prepend("<option value='' >&nbsp;</option>");
```

2 - Convert your select to chosen:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen({
    allow_single_deselect: true
});
```

3 - The option "allow_single_deselect" will create a red X in your option and it allows you to deselect and leave the field as a blank value:
[image]

Ref:
https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html